# How do I import a JavaScript library in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Right now I have a script loaded in Visual Studio where I am learning JS basics, but to do a challenge that calculates a massive number I want to load [this libary](https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html) in Visual Studio, how do I go about doing that?

I have read somewhere that in my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Section 2: JavaScript Language Basics</h1>
    </body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>


</html>
```

I have to replace "script.js" with the library, but wouldn't that make my existing code disappear?

Comment: There is importing. Just download the file and save it in your project and reference it. No different than how you do script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.2.5/math.js" integrity="sha256-NpsiqBNEmWcqc2vG1qGFrs8OPF7z+p0z9vTK68hXxbE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

just before closing `head` **or** `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

simple add a `<script src="<path to library>"></script>` in `head` section

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a client side library through the Visual Studio's menu:

1. Open the solution explorer
2. Right click your project
3. Select "Add"
4. Select "Client-Side Library. . ."
5. type "mathjs" {or your library name} in the Library field
6. click install

[image of the menu for library install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQBak.png)

This will add all the necessary files to your project. Then you can reference the scripts in your html 'head' just like OP

```
'<script src="<Path to Library>"></script>'
```